# Where are mutex locks defined in GCC?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, locking, mutex

I am looking at the `arena.c` file in GCC, which you can see at:

http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/arena.c.html#96

and more specifically:

```
#define arena_lock(ptr, size) do {                                              
      if (ptr)                                                                      
        (void) mutex_lock (&ptr->mutex);                                      
      else                                                                      
        ptr = arena_get2 (ptr, (size), NULL);                                      
   } while (0)
```

I would like to find out what `mutex_lock()` does exactly. Where can I find it's implementation?

EDIT: Found this but unsure if it matches my requirements?

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mutex.h

EDIT2 Above link doesn't contain a `mutex_lock()` implementation.

Comment: A little googling made me find [this link](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3c/mutex_lock/) and many others. Took me only a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this page.

http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/nptl/malloc-machine.h.html

it has mutex_lock() defination.

ANother link in your question has kernel space implemntation.

---

You should download whole `glibc` source code and then using `ctags` you should browse code.

Comment: ctags is CLI tool to brouse code in Linux. For windows you can use source insight or other IDE to read such large c project.